# How to access rows content type

Tags: php, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to access the row content type to write an IF condition.
please find below the view twig file.

```html
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

I try the following but not working.

```
{% for key, row in rows %}
{% if row._entity.gettype == 'warnings'%}
 {{row.content}}
{% else %}
  Nothing
{% endif %}
{{kint(row)}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should be able to inspect the contents of the rows array / collection by dumping it in twig like so: `{{ dump(rows) }}` - that should let you check if the structure matches your expectations

Answer (score -1):

You can use keys this way to iterate through the rows.

```
{% for key in rows|keys %}
   {{ rows[key].content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps ;)